# Does temperature affect a substances mass?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, mass

So I'm currently learning thermodynamics from the Openstax AP Physics book but a statement has arisen that I'm confused about. As you can see in the picture, I've highlighted the text that, to me, doesn't make sense with what the rest of the chapter says.

Does temperature affect the mass of a substance? I personally would think the higher temperature affects the gasoline density because it expands, therefore changing the volume, therefore the density, but the mass?

Can someone tell me whether the gasoline mass is changing with temperature or if it 's just a mistake in the book

[image]

Comment: That article has incorrect wording.

Answer (score 2):

Temperature does not affect mass. But it can affect mass per volume (density), which is what this seems to be saying. If your fuel gauge, which measures volume, reports x liters in the tank, but it is hot, you have less mass of gas than if it was cold and the fuel gauge reported the same volume

Answer (score 0):

That's easy to understand from the giving some numbers. Suppose the tank has a volume of 1 liter in the winter. Then You can fill up one-liter gasoline in it in winter. Now, Once you fill up the tank in winter and let the time pass, In summer since tank and gasoline going to have thermal expansion. So let that tank goes to 1.1 L and gasoline to 1.4 L, then it's clear that the gasoline (0.3 L) going to overflow.

Now because of the increase in the volume, the density is decreased and hence the mass. Because the mass is less in summer, You will travel less in summer than winter.

Answer (score -1):

**Conservation of mass**
There is a fundamental law of [conservation of mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_mass), which is usually mentioned in basic texts on physics or chemistry, but is usually quickly forgotten, since it seems very obvious.

In a bit more advanced texts it appears in the form of the continuity equation, which may seem too abstract to apply to real life situations:
$$
\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot\mathbf{j}=0.
$$

In either case it means that *mass does not appear and does not vanish, but merely flows from one place to another*. So, if no gasoline is added or consumed, and no gasoline is evaporated, its mass remains constant.

**Energy-mass equivalence**
The above is however not true in relativistic setting (which is not what interests us here), where a hotter object will likely have higher energy and therefore higher mass, see [energy-mass equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence).